# Daily schedule in BigQuery using data from Firebase analytics

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

So I have created a daily schedule in BigQuery using "Append to table" preference, so every day it adds yesterday's data to my specified table. I have scheduled to run this query every day at 9AM, but the issue is that sometimes Firebase creates previous day data table in BigQuery later then 9AM.

The example of daily scheduled SELECT I would be using is:

```
SELECT * FROM `analytics.events_*` WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

What would be the best practice to schedule a daily update for the previous day in BigQuery from Firebase, so there are no times where I am missing days?

Answer (score 0):

Bigquery Schedules are set to run at fixed times. If your incoming data is varying in delivery time then BigQuery Schedules are not what you're looking for.

But if you insist in using BigQuery Schedules, you could just relax the `WHERE` condition and catch "missing" days the next time the schedule runs. Then you flipped your problem and instead need to handle the case of not appending already appended rows (also increasing query cost):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `analytics.events_*` 
LEFT JOIN [target dataset].[target table] AS T
USING (event_name, event_timestamp, user_pseudo_id)
WHERE T.event_name IS NULL
AND T.event_timestamp IS NULL
AND T.user_pseudo_id IS NULL
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX >= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY))
```

Or you could alternatively modify the query into an `INSERT` statement where you insert records and handle duplications similarly:

```
INSERT `[target dataset].[target table]`
SELECT *
FROM `analytics.events_*` 
LEFT JOIN `[target dataset].[target table]` AS T
USING (event_name, event_timestamp, user_pseudo_id)
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX >= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY))
AND T.event_name IS NULL
AND T.event_timestamp IS NULL
AND T.user_pseudo_id IS NULL
```

Then you wouldn't need to configure a destination table for the schedule.

Futhermore, if your target table is timestamp partitioned, you can reduce amount of data scanned by limiting the range in which you scan in the target table by adding an additional `WHERE` condition that strictly limits to a single date instead of the entire table:

```
...
AND DATE(T.event_timestamp) = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2)
...
```